# How correctly filtering a CostumAdapter for a AutoCorrectTextView

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-filter

How can I still filter Results when I delete some output, while using a Custom Adapter?

```
private ArrayList<City> items, suggestions;
private Context mContext;
protected CityAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<City> cities) {
    super(context, resource, cities);
    this.items=cities;
    this.mContext = context;
    suggestions = new ArrayList<City>();
}
```

This is my code on the Filter On the Adapter:

```
     @Override
                    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                        if (constraint != null){
                            ArrayList<City> suggestions = new ArrayList<City>();
                            for (City city : citys) {
                                //Decide Later
                                // Note: change the "contains" to "startsWith" if you only want starting matches
                                if (city.getName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                                    suggestions.add(city);
                                }
                                results.values = suggestions;
                                results.count = suggestions.size();
                            }
                        }
                        return results;
                    }
    @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                clear();
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    // we have filtered results
                    addAll((ArrayList<City>) results.values);
                } else {
                    // no filter, add entire original list back in
                    addAll(citys);
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
```

[image]

As you can see when i delete a char the auto-complete doesn't give the expected value.

Comment: The filtering should be done by searching the **original** list of data(so you have all the entries at your disposal). Most likely the citys list is the one which is backing your adapter so every time you filter the list you leave it with fewer elements, elements which will not be available when you delete a part of the search string.

Comment: I may be thinking it wrong, but when i do the ArrayList<City> suggestions im not creating a new array? Whit only the selected values?

Comment: @JoãoMarques The suggestions list is not important. You need to have in your adapter a list containing all the elements of the adapter and use that for filtering(instead of the current *citys* list). Have a look at the source code of ArrayAdapter and how that class is doing it's filtering. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#ArrayAdapter.%3Cinit%3E%28android.content.Context%2Cint%2Cjava.util.List%29